# Mouse and keybord stutter when connecting though a USB hub

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, docking-station

I have a stutter issue when connecting USB peripherals (USB-connected mouse, keyboard) through a USB hub. I have attempted to troubleshoot to the best of my abilities, but haven't managed to solve the issue an am running out of ideas. Any further suggestions on what it could be or how to solve it would be greatly appreciated.

In my WFH desk setup I switch between using a work Thinkpad laptop and a private Lenovo Y530 throughout the day. To make this simpler, I'm attempting tu use a USB hub to connect my usual USB peripherals (mouse, keyboard, headset) to reduce the number of cables, and fit it all into my limited slots. On my work machine this works flawlessly, but on my private Y530 laptop I get some serious stutter on USB devices.

**These issues with the Y530 machine include:**

- The mouse pointer freezing for a second or two a few times a minute.
- Keyboard input getting stuck on keys while typing normally (like thiiiiiiiiiii). It doesn't seem to be "buffering", but getting stuck and repeating the key that was pressed when contact was lost. Further keystrokes are lost until re-connection is established a moment later.
- Headsets loosing connection and windows switching sound to other devices.
- When switching from the generic hub to a USB-C laptop dock and testing to run screen by it, it occasionally goes black for a second every now and "looses connection" to the screen.

**This far in troubleshooting I've tried:**

1. Using different USB ports on the Y530 laptop, no change.
2. Connecting the USB devices directly to the Y530 laptop instead of though a USB hub. Doing this the devices works excellently, and the USB peripherals works well with several other machines.
3. Using a different USB hub. Primarily I have tried to use a bog standard USB 3.1 hub which gives the mentioned stutter effects. When replacing it with a USB-C laptop dock and connecting it to a USB-C instead of the USB-A ports, it gives the same problems.
4. Connecting the same setups (different devices, both docks) to a different laptop (my work Thinkpad). No issues. Since the problems remains for several devices on only a single machine, I'm assuming it's something with my private laptop.
5. Only using a single low-tech device though the hub (such as a generic USB keyboard). It still stutters, so I figure it isn't likely a bandwith thing.

On the software side on the troubled Y530 I've tried:

6. To turn off USB selective suspend in power options. No change.
7. To turn off selective suspend in the device managed for the USB hub devices. No change.
8. To turn off "PCI Express Link State Power Management" in options. Not quite sure if it was relevant, so turned it off. No change.
9. To update and reinstall the USB hub drivers. No change.
10. To install the laptop dock drivers off Lenovo's webpage. No change.
11. To run the general windows and driver updates (using windows update and lenovo vantage apps). No change. The issues have persisted over several windows, driver and firmware updates - I first encountered this almost a year ago and have worked around it since while trying to figure it out. As such it isn't obviously a single recent update that broke something.
12. To run the "hardware scan" feature in the Lenovo vantage app. I mean, why not since it's there. It tells me my laptop, including PCIe and motherboard, is in shape.

**Laptop details:**

- The work machine is a Lenovo Thinkpad T14s Gen2 running Windows 10 (and seems well updated by corporate policies, I'm not a device admin). The USB hub(s) work well with this machine.
- The private machine is a Lenovo Y530-15ICH running windows 10. The USB hubs do not work well with this machine. (Specs: https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/Legion/Lenovo_Legion_Y530_15ICH/Lenovo_Legion_Y530_15ICH_Spec.pdf )

**USB hub details:**
I have attempted to use the Y530 laptop with the following two hubs

- A Deltaco USB 3.1 Gen 1 Hub (Model UH-481). (Specs: https://www.deltaco.lv/lven/accessories/computer-accessories/usb-hubs/deltaco-usb-3-1-gen-1-hub-4xtype-a-female-aluminum-0-3m-black-uh-481.html )
- A Lenovo ThinkPad USB-C Dock Gen2 (Model 40AS) (Specs: https://support.lenovo.com/se/en/solutions/acc500106-thinkpad-usb-c-dock-gen-2-overview-and-service-parts )

Comment: I have this exact issue also with my work laptop which is a Lenovo ThinkPad Carbon X1 gen. 9 and a generic Zeskris usb-c hub. I connect a Logitech universal receiver for my k800 keyboard and Mx master mouse and I very often get the repeated keystrokes every minute or two, and the mouse stutter. I have not found a solution and instead have to plug my receiver directly to a usb-a port on the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Are these the only USB peripherals connected to said laptop (or are there also HDDs, printers, USB headsets and other devices connected)?

I'm wondering if it's a USB power issue on your private laptop, I've had something similar with a past machine. The fix there was replacing the main board, I'm afraid.

You could definitively rule out anything OS based by using a linux live OS, for example Ubuntu: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install