# USB hub makes keyboard and mouse stutter on Windows 11

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, windows-11

I have the same problems as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1703145/mouse-and-keybord-stutter-when-connecting-though-a-usb-hub), on a PC with a B450 Tomahawk Max II mainboard, running Windows 11, and an active USB 3.0 hub.

I experience stuttering, freezing, lagging, and extra input (wrongly repeated keystrokes) of the keyboard & mouse when they are connected through a USB hub.

Sometimes this is relatively mild, other times insane (unusable PC).

- The same peripheral setup with the hub works fine on another system (note: a MacBook Pro, which doesn't have USB-A ports, so I mean using this hub with an additional USB-C to USB-A adapter).
- I also tried another old USB 2.0 hub, but the problem persisted.
- *Directly* plugged into the USB ports on the case, the keyboard and mouse work without problems.

**This problem does not appear when booting on Ubuntu Live.**

It also appeared for no reason - the hub worked in the past fine with Windows 11.

Of course, I already updated all drivers and BIOS.

I want/need to use a hub on Windows 11. What other things can I try?

A clean installation is kind of the last resort, and I don't even know if the issue just doesn't appear again immediately again.

**Update:**

**After installing the update to 22621.1928 it got much worse.**

Comment: Have you tried different hubs?

Comment: @music2myear yes, as I mentioned in the question